# Removing help_text in Django admin from read only fields

Tags: django, forms, python-2.7, django-forms, django-admin

So I have an admin like so:

```
class BlahAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (
        'name', 'status', 'created_date'
    )
    readonly_fields = (
        'created_date'
    )
```

And each of these fields has an annoying `help_text` that I don't want to display. Now I can get rid of two of them fine with

```
class BlahForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlahForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for fieldname in ['name', 'status']:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None
```

and adding the line

```
form = BlahForm
```

to `BlahAdmin`, but if I tried to add `created_date` to the field names looped over I get a 500 error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you define the help text, in the model? Can you just remove it? If not you can do this:

```
class BlahAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blah
        fields = '__all__'
        help_texts = {"created_date": None}
```

and still add this to your `BlahAdmin`:

```
form = BlahAdminForm
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I needed!